# Is there an example for Implicit Vs Explicit threading in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I was wondering what the difference is between implicit and explicit threading in Java and would appreciate it if I could see an example of both.

Comment: What's your definition of implicit and explicit threading?

Comment: Where did you hear/read these terms?

Comment: You might be thinking of implicit parallelism: here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814411/1152524) you're looking for related to Java.